# Unexpected behaviour in numpy np.where with np.logical_and

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find an RGB pixel in a numpy tri-dimensional array (X/Y/RGB) created with Pillow

```
conditions = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(array[:,:,0]==rgb[0],array[:,:,1]==rgb[1]),array[:,:,2]==rgb[2])
res = np.flip(np.transpose(np.where(conditions))).tolist()
```

It works like a charm.

However, I'd like to add a tolerance, so I just changed the conditions by:

```
abs(array[:,:,i]-rgb[i]) <= tolerance
```

But this does not work as expected, it returns zeros instead of pixels in the tolerated range.
How can I add tolerance to my upper snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was calling `np.array()` on a PIL Image automatically create a `dtype=uint8`. During my logical tests value can go higher than 255, thus the unexpected behaviour

Logic can be changed to make it work, but `array = np.array(im,dtype=np.int16)` also does the trick (even if it's less optimized)

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems as though it correctly identifies values within the given tolerance.

Here's my test code:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.reshape(np.array([i%3 + (i//3) / 10 for i in range(27)]), (3,3,3))
print('array:', array, '', sep='\n')
rgb = [0,1,2]
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print(f'x={x} y={y} rgb={array[x,y,:]}')

conditions = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(array[:,:,0]==rgb[0],array[:,:,1]==rgb[1]),array[:,:,2]==rgb[2])
print('', 'conditions:', conditions, sep='\n')
res = np.flip(np.transpose(np.where(conditions))).tolist()
print(res)
print('', 'res:', res, sep='\n')

tolerance = 0.35
conditions = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(abs(array[:,:,0]-rgb[0]) <= tolerance,abs(array[:,:,1]-rgb[1]) <= tolerance),abs(array[:,:,2]-rgb[2]) <= tolerance)
print('', f'conditions @ tolerance={tolerance}:', conditions, sep='\n')
res = np.flip(np.transpose(np.where(conditions))).tolist()
print(res)
print('', 'res:', res, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
array:
[[[0.  1.  2. ]
  [0.1 1.1 2.1]
  [0.2 1.2 2.2]]

 [[0.3 1.3 2.3]
  [0.4 1.4 2.4]
  [0.5 1.5 2.5]]

 [[0.6 1.6 2.6]
  [0.7 1.7 2.7]
  [0.8 1.8 2.8]]]

x=0 y=0 rgb=[0. 1. 2.]
x=0 y=1 rgb=[0.1 1.1 2.1]
x=0 y=2 rgb=[0.2 1.2 2.2]
x=1 y=0 rgb=[0.3 1.3 2.3]
x=1 y=1 rgb=[0.4 1.4 2.4]
x=1 y=2 rgb=[0.5 1.5 2.5]
x=2 y=0 rgb=[0.6 1.6 2.6]
x=2 y=1 rgb=[0.7 1.7 2.7]
x=2 y=2 rgb=[0.8 1.8 2.8]

conditions:
[[ True False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
[[0, 0]]

res:
[[0, 0]]

conditions @ tolerance=0.35:
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True False False]
 [False False False]]
[[0, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]

res:
[[0, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: ty for your tests, I had to undergo hours of testing to understand why it was working for you and not for me, you don't have any value close to uint8 limit so you did not replicate the problem, please check my answer